# Internet Explorer 10 not reading jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

I have a jQuery load function to create and add a  after images using the alt tag data. It works in every browser and IE9, just not IE10 and I can't figure out why.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$("img.caption").load(function () {
    var imageCaption = $(this).attr("alt"); 
    if (imageCaption != '') {
        var imgWidth = $(this).width();
        $("<figcaption class='img-caption'><em>" + imageCaption + "</em></figcaption>").css({ "position": "relative", "bottom": 0, "left": 0, "width": imgWidth + "px" }).insertAfter(this);
    }
    var figcaptionHeight = $('.img-caption').outerHeight();
    $('.img-caption').css('margin-top', -(figcaptionHeight + 2));
});
```

I've even tried using other tags like  but there's no response at all.

This is the HTML markup:

```
<figure>
     <img class="caption" alt="caption text" /> 
</figure>
```

Comment: Did you check the error console?

Comment: It says "zero elements found by selector" which is what is confusing me cause every other browser is having no problem and it's not like it's a complex selector.

Comment: Where's the `.src` attribute for your image tags?  It won't generate a `load` event with an image URL to actually load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to hook the load event for images specified in the HTML of your page, you cannot reliably do that with javascript.  This is because some images (particularly images in the browser cache already) may load BEFORE your JS runs and before you get the event handler installed and thus you will never be notified of the load event.

This is particularly an issue in some versions of IE.

You also won't get a `.load()` event if you haven't specified a `.src` attribute for your image tag as the whole purpose of the `load` event is to notify you when the image URL has finished loading.

Assuming you are specifying a `.src` URL, there are several possible solutions:

1. Put `onload` handlers into the HTML since these will be in place from the beginning.
2. When your JS runs, check all your images to see if some have already completed loading.  You can process those immediately and then install `.load()` handlers on the ones that haven't yet completed loading.

Here's an example for option #2 where you check to see if the image is already loaded and, if so, just process it immediately otherwise wait for the `load` event:

```
$("img.caption").each(function() {

    function processImage() {
        var imageCaption = $(this).attr("alt"); 
        if (imageCaption != '') {
            var imgWidth = $(this).width();
            $("<figcaption class='img-caption'><em>" + imageCaption + "</em></figcaption>").css({ "position": "relative", "bottom": 0, "left": 0, "width": imgWidth + "px" }).insertAfter(this);
        }
        var figcaptionHeight = $('.img-caption').outerHeight();
        $('.img-caption').css('margin-top', -(figcaptionHeight + 2));        
    }

    // if image already loaded, process it now
    if (this.complete) {
        processImage.call(this);
    } else {
        // wait for it to be loaded
        $(this).load(processImage);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

IE might not like the `$("img.caption")` instead try just `$(".caption")`

Comment: Why the ---- wouldn't it like that?

Comment: because its Internet Explorer.

Comment: -1 While I do agree that IE can be flaky, jQuery looks to normalize this flakiness. `img.caption` is a completely valid selector. The ***Sizzle*** engine behind jQuery selector's works the same across the main browsers, including IE 10. It's most likely do to a caching issue with the images.